# Passing multiple parameters to an SQLite query in Racket

Tags: sqlite, racket

I'm trying to pass more than one variable to an sqlite query in Racket.

```
(define select-test
  (prepare dbconn "SELECT count(*) FROM All_data WHERE Season = ? AND Division = '?'"))
(define season 2019)
(define league "E0")
;(query-value dbconn select-test '(season league))
;(query-value dbconn select-test season league)
```

There are examples online showing both a list and separate variables as input to a query, but neither of these are working for me.

I either get this message for the list:

```
query-value: cannot convert given value to SQL type
  given: '(season league)
  type: parameter
  dialect: SQLite
```

or 'wrong number of parameters for query' if done separately.

Can someone please help with the correct syntax?

Comment: Not totally sure, but in the [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/db/query-api.html#(def._((lib._db%2Fbase..rkt)._query-value))) it looks like the query needs to be given to `query-value` as a string, where the format bits look like `$1` rather than `?`

Comment: @MLavrentyev Yes, the use of `$1` or `?` depends upon the database being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your SQL. This statement:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM All_data WHERE Season = ? AND Division = '?'
```

has one parameter (for the Season comparison). The `'?'` is just a literal string containing a question mark. Just write `?` instead, like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM All_data WHERE Season = ? AND Division = ?
```

Then call it with two arguments, like this:

```
(query-value dbconn select-test season league)
```

By the way, you can double-check the number of parameters the prepared statement has with

```
(length (prepared-statement-parameter-types select-test))
```

With SQLite, there isn't any information in the types themselves, but the length tells you the number of parameters.

Comment: Ah, I see - so I assume the quotes are added to the statement when the variables are inserted? Thank you.

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, you can understand calling a parameterized query as replacing the placholders with SQL literals, including the quotes (and escaping) in the case of string values. But that's not how it's actually implemented. Think of a parameterized statement as SQL's version of a function. The SQL statement is parsed and compiled to a query plan, and when it is called with parameters, it uses their values in the execution of the query plan. There's no step that involves filling in the parameters to make a new string containing SQL code.